# Singly Linked List - Segmentation Error due to Destructor implementation

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, nodes, destructor

I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting a seg-error from my singly linked list implementation.

I create an object of type Deque called dq1, compiler calls the destructor for it since the program is done - destructor calls remove_front() which deals with some move()'s for the head. I believe this is where the problem lies but I can't seem to figure out where exactly it is.

Debugger Info - Dont know what to make of this?

```
#0 0x4013ea std::unique_ptr<Node, std::default_delete<Node> >::get(this=0x8) (/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:305)
#1 0x401586 std::unique_ptr<Node, std::default_delete<Node> >::operator bool(this=0x8) (/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:319)
#2 0x40140b std::operator!=<Node, std::default_delete<Node> >(std::unique_ptr<Node, std::default_delete<Node> > const&, decltype(nullptr))(__x=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x8>) (/usr/include/c++/6/bits/unique_ptr.h:670)
#3 0x401132 Deque::size(this=0x7fffffffe520) (Deque.cpp:75)
#4 0x4010f2 Deque::empty(this=0x7fffffffe520) (Deque.cpp:66)
#5 0x4016dd main() (/test.cpp:12)
```

Deque.cpp

```
#include "Deque.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <stdexcept>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::move;

Deque::~Deque()
{
    while (!empty()) remove_front();
}


void Deque::insert_front(int a)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Node> new_node;
    new_node->val = move(a);
    new_node->next = move(head); // head is wiped.
    head = move(new_node); //head is init. with new_node val*/
}


int Deque::remove_front()
{
    if (empty()) {throw std::runtime_error(std::string("Empty"));};

    std::unique_ptr<Node> old;
    int return_value = head->val;
    old = move(head);
    head = move(old->next);
    delete &old;
    return return_value;
}


bool Deque::empty() const
{
return (size() == 0);
}
int Deque::size() const
{

int size_val = 0;
const Node* p = head.get();

while ( p != NULL)
    {
        size_val++;
        p = p->next.get();
    }
    return size_val;
}
```

test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Deque.h"



using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{

     Deque dq1;
      return 0;
}
```

deque.h

```
#include "Node.h"
#include <memory>

class Deque{
    public:
        Deque() = default;
        Deque(const Deque&);
        ~Deque(); //must use constant space
        Deque& operator=(const Deque&){return *this;};
        void insert_front(int); 
        int remove_front();
        bool empty() const;

    private:
    friend Node;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> head ;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> tail ;

};
```

Node.h

```
#include "Node.h"

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Node& n) {
  return out << &n << ": " << n.val << " -> " << n.next.get();
}
```

Comment: You should **never** call `delete` on the pointer owned by a `std::unique_pointer`. Check your `int Deque::remove_front()` implementation in your *Deque.cpp*

Comment: Then how does the destructor deallocate memory used by a unique pointer?

Comment: @TigerCode http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: Thank you @GMichael 
`when the managing unique_ptr object is assigned another pointer via operator= or reset().`

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still running into a seg-fault after removing the `delete *old` line.

Comment: Missing `Node.h` to run [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: debugger helps.

Comment: I don't know how to use `std::unique_pointer` in such a way that it presents any advantage here, I might be wrong. Is this part of some homework where using `std::unique_pointer` is mandatory? Surely you know how to make a simple linked list with pointers.

Comment: Yea it is part of a homework question @BarmakShemirani
 Debugger? I had a look at it but wasn't sure what to make of it. I'll post it up once im at school

Comment: @karastojko I left it out for making the post clear - sorry about that. I'll add it in soon

Comment: If you use `std::unique_ptr` you do not need to do anything in destructor in this case.

Comment: @slava 

Yea I was wondering if I could just leave it blank as per the many other examples i've seen where they use unique_ptrs. 

I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Still getting a seg-fault - the  answer probably lies in the debugger info, I'll need to decipher that first i suppose

Comment: @TigerCode According to the debugger information the problem is in `Deque::size`, post it's code here.

Comment: @Nikita implementation of `empty()` is there, you need to scroll code.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Not sure I understand your statement; it's easily possible to write a singly (or doubly) linked list where all the memory management is handled by `unique_ptr`, and you get guaranteed absence of any leaks (even under exceptions) for free (and you never need to write `new` or `delete`).

Comment: @Nikita You're right, I've included it in the post now. Debugger also threw me at the size() function

Comment: @NirFriedman This is not "easily possible". In fact it seems the asker is still unable to finish the linked list class, despite having an answer. `std::unique_pointer` does not magically solve every issue, as demonstrated in this topic. I have no idea how `std::unique_pointer<Node> head` is of any help here. If `Node` had its own `std::unique_pointer` then it is possible that each node could manage the memory of the next node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have UB right here:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> new_node;
new_node->val = move(a);
```

you create a new pointer that is default initialized (points to `nullptr`) and you dereference it. You should initialize it with `std::make_unique` if you have C++14 or later or just initialize it with `new`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> new_node = std::make_unique<Node>(); // C++14 or later
std::unique_ptr<Node> new_node( new Node ); // pre C++14
```

This line also has issue:

```
delete &old;
```

this line does not make any sense. You get address of pointer itself, which is created as local variable and try to delete it. If you tried to delete data, where `old` points to, that is ether wrong - whole point of `std::unique_ptr` is to do that automatically.

This member:

```
std::unique_ptr<Node> tail ;
```

this is wrong by design, though you do not seem to use it in your code. This assumes you are going to have multiple `std::unique_ptr` to point to the same object. But this pointer is for unique ownership.

You seem to have issue in `Deque::size()` as well, but without seeing source it is impossible to say what is wrong there.

In your destructor you do not need to do anything (though it would not harm if other methods are implemented properly) - `std::unqiue_ptr` will destroy all data recursively.

Comment: I forgot to include size() in the post - I've included it now. Thats where my debugger has lead me. @Slava

Comment: I believe it has to do with the way I've created the node pointer P

Comment: @TigerCode `size()` looks OK, it seems that issue of using `nullptr` in `insert_front()` breaks it.

Comment: For the tail - it needs to be an observer then since we cant have head = tail be two unique ptrs correct?

Comment: Tail can be a raw pointer, otherwise you have issue, as `Node` is owned by either `head` or previous `Node::next` and you cannot have more than one owner with `std::unque_ptr`. Also you can use `std::shared_ptr`, but in this case it would be overkill.

Comment: Question said not to use shared_ptr - I think just `observer_ptr<Node> Tail;` should suffice but I'll have to figure out how to use it in the implementation/where I need to include it.

Comment: `observer_ptr` is not in standard (yet?) but if you allowed to use that, sure. Technically that is just a wrapper over a raw pointer.